# Intercept and manipulate SQL messages between Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a idea for a different data-layer. I want to load balance between different sql servers. To do so I have the following setup in mind:

[image]

When the webapplication does a SQL request, the "Application Proxy" checks if it is a SELECT statement or not. When it is a SELECT statement the "Application Proxy" sends the SELECT statement to 1 server. When it is not a SELECT statement it sends the request to all servers.

Now I know the idea in this state will not work and I have to solve a lot of different problems to get it to work (and yes, there are solutions for this already). But for now, the biggest startup problem is the intergration with Entity Framework.

What I want is to wrap a DbContext in my own class so I can intercept the messages and send them myself. So something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override string DoCallToServer(string sqlrequest)
    {
        if (sqlrequest.ToLower().StartsWith("select"))
        {
            return MyEngine.CallAll(sqlrequest);
        }
        else
        {
            return MyEngine.CallOne(sqlrequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

I've searched the internet, but I could not find anything.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BuildingBlocks

Comment: this is a very good example but I think you need at least EF 6 or higher  (im not sure you have to check it out!) http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

Comment: @bassam, why didn't you post that as a answer? That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good exmaple for interceptors:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

another excellent example which is very good but unfortunately only in Germans:
https://entwickler.de/online/entity-framework-6-1-neue-interceptors-und-mehr-161541.html